# ImageView on orientation change - Drawable ignores setBounds and returns to original state

Tags: android, screen-orientation, android-imageview, invalidation, android-framelayout

### EDIT 3:

I am maintaining the original question below for historical reasons. However, I have found that the issue is not isolated to `FrameLayout`. Hence, updated the title.

Instead of over-crowding this post with more code, I have created a sample project which demonstrates the issue; and [uploaded](https://code.google.com/p/android-drawable--invalidation-on-orientation-issue/downloads/list) it on Google Project Hosting.

The summary of the issue is this:

> A drawable in portrait orientation with a certain bounds set on it, on
>   changing orientation and returning to portrait, does not retain the
>   set bounds. Instead it reverts to its original bounds. This is in
>   spite of forcefully setting the explicit bounds on orientation change.
>   Do note that any bounds that you later set on Click etc are obeyed.

I have also [uploaded a version of the app](http://code.google.com/p/android-drawable--invalidation-on-orientation-issue/downloads/detail?name=InvalidateDrawable_2012_FEB_14_01.zip&can=2&q=) that contains 2 separate activities illustrating the issue.

1. Plain vanilla activity that just illustrates the issue.
2. Activity that uses a custom `BitmapDrawable` on the `ImageView` - this one prints to log whenever bounds are being changed.

The second version show clearly that even if I set the bounds on the Drawable, these bounds are not being obeyed in `onBoundsChange()`.

---

**Original Question:**

I am using a `FrameLayout` with 2 `ImageView`s stacked one on top of the other for displaying a "Battery Status" graphic. This is in portrait mode. In Landscape mode, I display a different layout (a chart).

My issue is this - suppose the battery status is displaying - say 30%. Now, I rotate the screen and display the chart. When I come back to the Portrait orientation, **the battery graphic goes back to its original position** (which is "full").

I have tried all sorts of things to try and figure out what is happening. Debugging shows me that the bounds for the "top" graphic are indeed being set as expected. So this seems to be an invalidation issue. I am presenting the code for 2 classes and 2 layout XMLs (all simplified) which helps in reproducing the issue. Also attaching the placeholder PNGs used for the ImageViews.

[image: Placeholder Battery Frame graphic] [image: Placeholder Battery Content graphic]

Can anyone spot the error? To recreate the issue, run the app, and click in "Update" button. The graphic will be "filled" to a certain level. Then, switch to landscape and then back to Portrait. The graphic does not remember its earlier value.

The Activity:

```
public class RotateActivity extends Activity {

    private View portraitView, landscapeView;
    private LayoutInflater li;
    private Configuration mConfig;
    private ValueIndicator indicator;
    private Button btn;
    private Random random = new java.util.Random();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        li = LayoutInflater.from(this);
        portraitView = li.inflate(R.layout.portrait, null);
        landscapeView = li.inflate(R.layout.landscape, null);
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        mConfig = newConfig;
        initialize();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        mConfig = getResources().getConfiguration();
        initialize();
        super.onResume();
    }

    private void initialize(){
        if(mConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE){
            displayLandscape();
        } else {
            displayPortrait();
        }
    }

    private void displayLandscape() {
        setContentView(landscapeView);
    }

    private void displayPortrait() {
        setContentView(portraitView);
        btn = (Button)portraitView.findViewById(R.id.button1);
        indicator = (ValueIndicator)portraitView.findViewById(R.id.valueIndicator1);
    /*
     * Forcing the graphic to perform redraw to its known state when we return to portrait view.
     */
    indicator.updateIndicatorUi();  



        btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                updateIndicator(random.nextInt(100));
            }
        });

    }

    private void updateIndicator(int newValue){
        indicator.setPercent(newValue);
    }
}
```

portrait.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <com.gs.kiran.trial.inval.ValueIndicator
                android:id="@+id/valueIndicator1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="10dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Update" />

</LinearLayout>
```

ValueIndicator.java

```
public class ValueIndicator extends FrameLayout {

    private ImageView ivFrame, ivContent;
    private Drawable drFrame, drContent;
    private Rect mBounds;
    private int currentTop;
    private int mPercent;

    public ValueIndicator(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View root = li.inflate(R.layout.indicator, this, true);

        ivFrame = (ImageView) root.findViewById(R.id.ivFrame);
        ivContent = (ImageView) root.findViewById(R.id.ivContent);

        drFrame = ivFrame.getDrawable();
        drContent = ivContent.getDrawable();

        mBounds = drFrame.getBounds();

        Log.d(Constants.LOG_TAG, "Constructor of ValueIndicator");

    }

    public void setPercent(int newPercent){
       this.mPercent = newPercent;
       updateIndicatorUi();
    }

    public void updateIndicatorUi(){
        Rect newBounds = new Rect(mBounds);
        newBounds.top = mBounds.bottom - (int)(this.mPercent * mBounds.height() / 100);
        currentTop = newBounds.top;
        Log.d(Constants.LOG_TAG, "currentTop = "+currentTop);
        drContent.setBounds(newBounds);
        //invalidateDrawable(drContent);
        invalidate();
    }
}
```

indicator.xml (The XML for the FrameLayout used in the custom View)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/frameLayout1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivFrame"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/frame" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivContent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/content" />

</FrameLayout>
```

landscape.xml (dummy placeholder - sufficient to recreate the issue)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Landscape" />

</LinearLayout>
```

AndroidManifest.xml snippet:

```
<activity
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:name=".RotateActivity" 
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden">
            <intent-filter >
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

---

**EDIT**

I also tried calling `setPercent()` and pass in a saved value in `displayPortraitView()` - basically forcing an update to a known state whenever we get back to portrait mode. Still no luck. Do note that the logs tell me that the bounds of the drawables are correct. I can't figure out why the invalidation doesn't happen.

---

**EDIT 2:**

1. In ValueIndicator.java, I introduced a member variable `mPercent`
   which always stores the last known percent value.
2. Updated the `setPercent()` code to update the member variable `mPercent`; and then call the `updateIndicateUi()` method.
3. `updateIndicatorUi()` (which is now a `public` method) now uses the state (i.e, `mPercent`) to do its job.
4. Whenever we are back to portrait mode, I call `updateIndicatorUi()`. This forces the battery graphic to update itself.

I also updated the code to reflect these changes.

The idea is to force a redraw and an invalidate whenever we return from landscape to portrait mode. Again - I do see the bounds of the battery "content" drawable being set as desired, but the UI refuses to keep pace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've examined your code on Google Code Hosting (appreciate your effort to document the code so thoroughfully), and I found that the bounds set on the Drawable is indeed changed *again* when you go back to the portrait from landscape orientation.

The bounds on the Drawable is changed not by your code, but by `ImageView`'s layout method. When you place a new layout (`setContentView`), all layoutting code is run, including `ImageView`'s. `ImageView` *changes* the bound of the drawable that it contains, that's why you get the bounds of the drawable changed to the original one.

The stack trace leading to the bound change is:

```
Thread [<1> main] (Suspended (entry into method onBoundsChange in BitmapDrawable))  
    BitmapDrawable.onBoundsChange(Rect) line: 293   
    BitmapDrawable(Drawable).setBounds(int, int, int, int) line: 131    
    ImageView.configureBounds() line: 769   
    ImageView.setFrame(int, int, int, int) line: 742    
    ImageView(View).layout(int, int, int, int) line: 7186   
    LinearLayout.setChildFrame(View, int, int, int, int) line: 1254 
    LinearLayout.layoutVertical() line: 1130    
    LinearLayout.onLayout(boolean, int, int, int, int) line: 1047   
    LinearLayout(View).layout(int, int, int, int) line: 7192    
    FrameLayout.onLayout(boolean, int, int, int, int) line: 338 
    FrameLayout(View).layout(int, int, int, int) line: 7192 
    LinearLayout.setChildFrame(View, int, int, int, int) line: 1254 
    LinearLayout.layoutVertical() line: 1130    
    LinearLayout.onLayout(boolean, int, int, int, int) line: 1047   
    LinearLayout(View).layout(int, int, int, int) line: 7192    
    PhoneWindow$DecorView(FrameLayout).onLayout(boolean, int, int, int, int) line: 338  
    PhoneWindow$DecorView(View).layout(int, int, int, int) line: 7192   
    ViewRoot.performTraversals() line: 1145 
    ViewRoot.handleMessage(Message) line: 1865  
    ViewRoot(Handler).dispatchMessage(Message) line: 99 
    Looper.loop() line: 130 
    ActivityThread.main(String[]) line: 3835    
    Method.invokeNative(Object, Object[], Class, Class[], Class, int, boolean) line: not available [native method]  
    Method.invoke(Object, Object...) line: 507  
    ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() line: 847  
    ZygoteInit.main(String[]) line: 605 
    NativeStart.main(String[]) line: not available [native method]
```

When reading your code I found it overkill to change bounds and storing the bounds etc. just to draw a meter. May I suggest one of the following:

1. Change the size of the `ImageView` itself (using `setLayoutParams`) instead of the bounds of its drawable.
2. Instead of using ImageView, create a class extending `View` and override `onDraw(Canvas)` and then draw the red rectangle using `drawRect`.

Comment: Thanks for the inputs. Really appreciate. Actually, this was a "dummy" image. My real app displays battery status using a `FrameLayout` in which I have 3 high quality images - the battery "frame", the battery "background" in black & the battery "content" in green. I researched quite a bit on the best way to display battery status graphically in Android & concluded that `setBounds` is the way to go. Because of this I think the plain custom `View` with `onDraw` solution might not be suitable for me. I will experiment with suggestion 1 and report back.

Comment: Just thinking aloud: even if the `ImageView` changes the bounds at the time of layout; I am still *forcibly* setting the bounds *after* `setContentView()`. Why are the new bounds I specify not being obeyed? I noticed that `setImageDrawable()` in turn calls `requestLayout()` - so to mitigate this; I moved the `setImageDrawable()` code to `onCreate()` instead of `displayPortrait()`. Still no improvement.

Comment: An update: I am trying a solution which extends `View` and then draws the image directly to screen with `graphics.drawBitmap()`. It may be slightly complicated since I need to decide on the proper strategy for `onMeasure()`. I hope to have something before the bounty expiry time.

Comment: I have committed the "working" code to google code project hosting. Thanks to you for pointing me in the right direction. I used a custom `View` with `canvas.drawBitmap()` to create the battery graphic. I will add more details in an answer to the original question.

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess, but in RotateActivity, try changing the order of the super call to this:

```
super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig); // super called before initialize()
mConfig = newConfig;
initialize();
```

Comment: Good catch! Doesn't work though. I tried a few more things that I updated in my question.

Comment: I don't really feel like reading through all your code, but why don't you set the size of the battery image the same way you do when it is first made every time it reloads? Just save the value (probly in the instansteState) and repeat the action.

Comment: Yes - I tried that already. That's what I mentioned in my Edit. Every time I get back to portrait orientation, I forcefully set the battery percentage. As I mentioned, the bounds are updated correctly. Its just that they don't "take effect". I even tried to force update in `onAttachedToWindow()` of the custom view - still no use.

Comment: Oops .. I edited the question but not the code itself. Will do that a little later.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by using a good old custom `View` object. In `onDraw()`, I draw the bitmaps to `Canvas`, and resize the bounds according to battery percent. Uploaded the archive for the working project [here](https://code.google.com/p/android-drawable--invalidation-on-orientation-issue/downloads/detail?name=InvalidateDrawable_2012_FEB_21_00.zip) at Google Project Hosting. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9305855/570930) helped me on my way and hence I have accepted and awarded the bounty.

I still am not convinced about the need for using a custom `View` for this though. IMO, I should be able to place the `ImageView` in a `Layout` and this should still work. I just can't figure out a way to tell the layout to leave my `Drawable`s alone!

Further, this battery graphic was originally intended to be used along with other graphics (temperature, signal strength ... ) in a 2-column table layout. So the applicability of this solution to those cases remains to be seen.

Also, my solution has a minor bug - the battery always appears empty the first time. I will upload the solution to the same project when I find the solution for this.